# React Multi-select dropdown implementation for the user

Tags: reactjs, multi-select

I would like to implement react multiselect option in my code. So far I designed a form which can take only one input for the team name and only one input for the member name. I would like to add multiple members under one team. I went through [this tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect-react-dropdown). But did not understand how I use it for my code block.

The source code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function TeamRoster({ setActive }) {
  const [rosterValues, setrosterValues] = useState({
    team_id: '',
    member_id: '',
  });


    const [allTeams, setAllTeams] = useState([{}]);
    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([{}]);


    const [submittedroster, setSubmittedroster] = useState([{}]);



    // Define a function to get the team name based on the team ID
    function getTeamName(teamId) {
      const teamname = allTeams.find((teams) => teams._id === teamId);

      if (!teamname) {
        return 'Unknown team';
      }

      return teamname.team_name;
    }
    function getUser(userId) {
      const username = allUsers.find((users) => users._id === userId);

      if (!username) {
        return 'Unknown user';
      }
  
      return `${username.firstName} ${username.lastName}`;
    }

   const handleInputChange = (event) => {

       const { name, value } = event.target;
       setrosterValues({ ...rosterValues, [name]: value });
      };

      const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();



        axios.post('http://localhost:9000/createTeamRoster', rosterValues)
  .then((res) => {

    if (res.data) {
      alert('Team with members creation Successful');

    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    alert('Error in creating the team and members');


  });
};
useEffect(() =>{

    axios
    .get('http://localhost:9000/getTeamRoster')
    .then(function(response){

      const allrosters = response.data;

      setrosterValues(allrosters);

      setSubmittedroster(allrosters);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });

    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getTeam')
    .then(function(response){
      const TeamData = response.data;

      setAllTeams(TeamData);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
    )
    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getUser')
    .then(function(response){
      const userData = response.data;

      setAllUsers(userData);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
    )

  }, []
);
return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title">Team member creation</h2>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label for="teamSelect">Team name:</label>

                  <select id="teamSelect"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="team_id"
                    value={rosterValues.team_id}

                   onChange={handleInputChange}

                  >

                    <option value ="">Select a team </option>
                    {allTeams.map((teams) => (
                      <option key={teams._id} value = {teams._id}>{teams.team_name}</option>

                    ))
                    }

                  </select>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                  <label for ="memberselect">Member Name</label>
                  <select id="memberselect"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="member_id"
                    value={rosterValues.member_id}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  >
                    <option value ="">Select a Member </option>
                    {allUsers.map((users) => (
                      <option key={users._id} value = {users._id}>{users.firstName} {users.lastName}</option>

                    ))
                    }
                    </select>
                </div>


                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                  create team rosters
                </button>
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


      <div className="row mt-5">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title">Submitted Values</h2>
              {submittedroster.map((rosters) => (
                <div key={rosters._id}>
                  <p><strong>TeamName:</strong> {getTeamName(rosters.team_id)}</p>
                  <p><strong>Member Name:</strong> {getUser(rosters.member_id)}</p>

                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>


  );



}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i read the package you want to use but i didn't find any code for OnSelect function to select values. why you are not using material ui multi select?